# Почта приходит в СПАМ

Tags: php, email

Вопрос почему почта приходит в СПАМ:

1. Это зависит от обработчика
2. От самого почтовика
3. Или еще от чего-то

Объясните почему так происходит!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во первых убедитесь что ваша почта действительно не спам.

Во вторых [поищите ваш ip](http://www.dnsbl.info/dnsbl-database-check.php) и [домен](http://www.dnsbl-check.info)  в базах dnsbl.

В третьих, посмотрите заголовки которые вы посылаете, убедитесь, что обратная запись dns для ip с которого вы посылаете совпадает с доменом в поле from (желательно), что MX запись для вашего домена существует,  прочитайте про spf и dkim.

Comment: У меня даже почта с Хешкода приходит в спам. Почта meta.ua.
Может от самого почтовика зависит, где расположена почта?